# Downloading a package on a directory accessible to Mathematica

Tags: packages

I am trying to download the Ricci.m file from [this page](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/). The instructions say

> You'll need to download the source file Ricci.m and save it in a directory accessible to Mathematica...Once you've successfully transferred all the Ricci files to your system, start up Mathematica and load the Ricci package....

When I'm clicking on the Ricci.m file on the page though, a web page with lots of text opens. I don't quite know how to download/save it on my computer. Also, how do I know which directory is accessible to Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

> Also, how do I know which directory is accessible to Mathematica?

These directories can be listed by evaluating [`$Path`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Path.html).

The standard place to put packages is the directory opened by the command

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

I suggest you put it there.

Comment: How do I download the file RIcci.m? Every time I click on it, a webpage with a lot of text opens. There seems to be no download option

Comment: @mathboy Right click, Save As? You might want to ask a friend sitting next to you for help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right mousebutton, then choose save-as.

Then open this file, and evaluate it.

You have then all functions defined in the package available to use. Read the

```
(* comments sections; or text between brackets and asterixes as indicated *)
```

to find out how to use these functions.